# Check the convergence of the series involving trigonometric function

Tags: sequences-and-series

Check whether the series is convergent?

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\tan(\frac{1}{n})$

Comment: How does $\tan(1/n)$ behave for large $n$?

Answer (score 2):

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\tan(\frac{1}{n}) =  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\frac{\sin(\frac{1}{n})}{\cos(\frac{1}{n})}$$ note.. $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1 \implies \sin(x)\approx x$$ for small $x$ values..  thus.. for large $n$'s $$\sin\left(\frac1n\right)\approx \frac1n$$ thus... 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\frac{\sin(\frac{1}{n})}{\cos(\frac{1}{n})}\approx \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\frac{ \frac{1}{n}}{\cos(\frac{1}{n})}$$ 
for large $n$'s $$\cos\left(\frac1n\right)\approx 1$$ thus... 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\frac{\sin(\frac{1}{n})}{\cos(\frac{1}{n})}\approx \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\frac{ \frac{1}{n}}{ 1} = \sum \frac{1}{n^{3/2}}$$ which clearly converges by recognizing it as a p-series, or integral test.. etc....

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:** Use the comparison test.